# how to reassign the button back in the browser in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, submit, nuxt.js

how to reassign the button back in the browser in vue js?
I want to intercept button presses back and do something in vue js (nuxt js)

Comment: more clarification please

Comment: more details please and some code if possible

Comment: let's say I have a menu. I want that when I press the button back, the menu is hidden.
Now implemented through the menu hash.

Comment: computed: {
      menu() {

        

        return this.$route.hash == '#menu' ? true : false;
      }
    },

Comment: but I would like to do everything in my mind. catch the back button and change the menu state